# How to fix ImportErrors when loading Python plugins in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, installation, windows

I have recently installed QGIS 1.8 in Windows 8. Although QGIS seems to be working fine, I cannot load plugins after their installation. Instead I keep getting this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 143, in loadPlugin
__import__(packageName)
File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named linear_ref
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I`ve figured out what the problem was. the nomenclature of my username was creating a conflict. The problem was solved by changing my windows user name.